# Identify the object in a playing video with the help of coordinates Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have found the coordinates (x,y,width,height) from a video (canvas looping) in angular. I need to identify the same rectangle in the video, While its playing with the help of coordinates(x,y,width,height).

```
video.addEventListener('play',function() {  ==> video played on canvas 
  var $this = this;
   (function loop() {
    if(!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
      context.drawImage($this, 0 ,0);
      setTimeout(loop,1000/30);
    }
  })();
},false)
```